# Pegar media de vendas de determinado mês

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Gostaria de pegar a média das vendas do mês pela descrição do produto e não pela data com dia, mês e ano, mas não sei como pegar.

```
SELECT AVG(vend_qtde) AS qtde_vendas from tb_vendas WHERE esto_descricao like '% Saco pedra %' and vend_data like '% 03/01/2018 %' GROUP BY esto_descricao;
```

Script do meu banco de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_vendas
(
    vend_cod serial NOT NULL,
    esto_descricao character(30) NOT NULL,
    vend_preco double precision,
    vend_qtde integer,
    vend_nome_cliente character(35),
    vend_cep character(20),
    vend_bairro character(25),
    vend_endereco character(38),
    vend_estado character(20),
    vend_uf character(13),
    vend_data character(20),
    vend_hora character(20),
    CONSTRAINT tb_vendas_pkey PRIMARY KEY (esto_descricao, vend_cod)
)
```

**Registros:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não utilize o 'like' para datas, utilize between ou maior e menor que.
Ex.:

```
select avg(a.vend_qtde) from tb_vendas a where a.esto_descricao like '%Saco pedra%' and vend_data between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-30'
```

ou

```
select avg(a.vend_qtde) from tb_vendas a where a.esto_descricao like '%Saco pedra%' and vend_data >= '2018-01-01' and vend_data <= '2018-01-30'
```

Também te aconselho a deixar o campo "esto_descricao" e qualquer outro que seja texto variável como do tipo VARCHAR e não CHARACTER.
Varchar ele usa somente o necessário de bytes, o charcater preencherá os 35 "espaços" mesmo se você usar somente 1.